# Displaying custom format in Bootstrap DatetimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm working with DateTimePicker of Bootstrap, I'm loading a view with multiple rows, everyone of these have a datetimepicker, I'm preloading the value from the database with a *timestamp* for example the datetime:

```
2016-01-05 04:00:00
```

That's working pretty good, but I want to show in the format *DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss* I has put that on the *format option* like this:

```
$('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
        locale: "es",
        stepping:15,
        format:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'    ,
        widgetPositioning:{
                            horizontal: 'auto',
                            vertical: 'bottom'
                        }
    });
```

But that's not working, that's is loading me a empty field. Then, I tried with the data attribute, adding this to the HTML tag:

```
data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"
```

But, it's giving me a field filled with something very strange, something like this (and that not makes sense to me):

```
20-01-0005 04:00:00
```

But, when I put: `data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"` works pretty well, but it's not my desired format. 
So, hoy can I do it? what kind of things should I to consider?
And thanks beforehand!

Comment: Did you try to use it in the html element?  <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

Comment: Its working fine. You can test it here. http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

Comment: @Franco Yes! I did, but that only works if the user if gonna fill an empty field. My field already have a value, the user only can changes it. And it's not showing the value give from the database in a valid format

Comment: @KethaKavya like I said, that works fine to a empty field. But it's not displaying very well a datetime preloaded from the database

Comment: If the input has value, the date format used should match that declared in the `format` option of the bootstrap datetime picker. If you need to display a different format than what is used in your database, it should really be converted prior to populating the form, and converted back before insertion in the database.

Comment: @JasonTate I was fearing that

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an array of formats with the [`extraFormats`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats) option or use [`keepInvalid`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepinvalid). I'd recommend you use `extraFormats` though.

```
extraFormat: ['...','....']
```